# How to pass copy of object in React useState Initial State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, use-state

**What I am trying to achieve is after fitlerRequest function called filterListValue should manipulate.**

**But what happening is on radioHandleChange it's start manipulating the filterListValue.**

**I think they have the same memory reference but how to make a copy of it?**

```
export default function CustomFilter(props) {
    const { filterListValue, setFilterListValue } = props;
const [radioValue, setRadioValue] = useState(filterListValue)

const radioHandleChange = (e, list) => {
        setRadioValue(radioValue => {
            let copy = [...radioValue]
            copy[indexChange].value = e.target.value
            copy[indexChange].id = list.id
            return copy
        });
}

const filterRequest = () => {
        setFilterListValue(radioValue)
        handleClose()
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make copies using `...`. Although not mentioned, looks like `props.filterListValue` is an array. So create a copy when starting with useState hook.
Also, when setting radio value, make a copy of the item (since it is an object) so you are not mutating the state by mistake.

```
    const { filterListValue, setFilterListValue } = props;
const [radioValue, setRadioValue] = useState([...props.filterListValue])

const radioHandleChange = (e, list) => {
        setRadioValue(radioValue => {
            let copy = [...radioValue]
            let copyItem = {...copy[indexChange]}; 
            copyItem[indexChange].value = e.target.value
            copyItem[indexChange].id = list.id
            return copyItem
        });
}
```

**PS:**

You can destructure inside the function argument parenthesis. It is common practice:

```
export default function CustomFilter({filterListValue, setFilterListValue}) {
```